# Application plugin fails at any optimization level other than -o0 OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, optimization, compiler-construction

I am running into a very odd problem when building an application plugin under XCode4. (Apple LLVM 4.2 )
The project in question builds a plugin file for an external application, which is basically a bundle, but with a different extension.
The plugin itself is doing some manipulation of video streams and has some pretty high throughput requirements, hence the need for decently optimized code.

BUT, as soon as I enable any optimization level other than None [-O0], the application takes forever to load my plugin, and as a result my plugin never gets used.
From my debugging so far i cannot see any obvious location where my code is failing,
or taking a different path compared to the un-optimized version of the code.
Earlier versions of the code used to compile fine using optimization under Xcode3,
however the addition of new features require more performance, and not using optimization is no longer acceptable.

So i am hoping someone can provide some tips on debugging / tracking down this issue?
It is all pretty standard C++, with some pthreads stuff.
Sadly i have not developed debugging skills or techniques for this particular situation.

The host application does provide a sample project, which does compile fine with optimizations turned on. However i am looking for debugging techniques methods, OTHER than simply rebuilding my project line by line to try and find the offending code.

Thanks in advance,

James.

PS. Be nice this is my first post here.  great resource btw.

Comment: I don't really know any specifics for this situation, but here are a couple suggestions of where to start looking: 1: try compiling different files with different optimization levels (if you have multiple files in your plugin) and figure out if it's just one file where the optimization causes a problem (and you can even break it down further by using #pragmas to set optimization on each function). 2: Try running gdb on the host process and pausing during the long load of your plugin, just to see where it's spending all its time.

Comment: Ohh thanks i didn't think of compiling specific files at different optimization levels, that will be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cobbal has already provided a suitable answer, 
ie. try enabling optimization on a file by file basis.

I have tried this, and now i have have the plugin compiling the file containing the CPU intensive code getting compiled with optimizations, i have also discovered which file contains the offending code.

Selective enabling of compile options on a file by file basis, can be a powerful debugging tool.

So thanks cobbal.

(not sure how to give him any credit for providing the correct answer)

Comment: For what it's worth, if a file is failing under optimizations, it's likely that there's some sort of subtle bug in it which is being exposed under optimization. Take a close look at that file, possibly with `clang --analyze`, and see if there's something not quite right.